# Eclipse hangs on Mac

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, freeze

I am developing android apps in Eclipse on a Macbook.  When I type any method which has to do with text Eclipse hangs and searches for the function.  It will eventually come back to me, but without what I was looking for.  I do not want to turn off the autocomplete feature, it saves me a lot of typing.

Any suggestions?

Examples of where Eclipse Hangs:

```
EditText.getText

TextView.getText

View.setText
```

Comment: yeah it's tough, same thing happens when i develop iPhone apps on my PC

Comment: I have found its any object class that contains a lot of methods.  Including View objects of course and super classes.  I am almost ready to go back to a PC, but like my mac and XCode.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution was to dual boot my MacBook. Using boot camp I am now running Eclipse under Windows XP Pro and Xcode under OSX 10.6.8